# Javascript equivalent of Ruby to_i

Tags: javascript, ruby

I need to reproduce the following Ruby code in Javascript but I can't find an equivalent for to_i.

```
beginning_of_last_full_hour = (Time.now.to_s.split(/:\d{2}/)[0] + ":00:00").to_time.to_i - 3600
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am trying to get the beginning of the last full hour. Thanks

Comment: `to_i` isn't really the important part. You need to convert a time object to a unix timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Javascript equivalent of Ruby to_i

`parseInt()`.

Follow this for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

> Converting following  code from Ruby to JavaScript:

```
(Time.now.to_s.split(/:\d{2}/)[0] + ":00:00").to_time.to_i
# => 1426788000
# Time.now # => 2015-03-19 18:45:22 +0530
```

JS equivalent:

```
d = new Date();
new Date( d.toString().split(/:\d{2}/)[0] + ":00:00").getTime();
# 1426788000
```

Comment: w3schools is frowned upon in these parts. You should change the link to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: sure @Max will do that :)

Comment: thanks! still needed to divide 1000 like the next poster said for them to be the same

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to take unix timestamp. In this case you should convert your `Date` object to it use:

```
date_object / 1000
```

or

```
date_object.getTime() / 1000
```

You should divide by 1000 because `to_i` for Ruby `Time` object return unix timestamp in seconds but `getTime()` return it in milliseconds.